# Mover imagenes simulando un estacionamiento javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes ,necesito su ayuda me pidieron hacer un pequeño estacionamiento en html usando javascript, no se mucho de javascript pero e podido hacer algo pero necesito mover unas imagenes que genero pidiendo la cantidad de un div a otro div, me aparece la opcion de moverlas y soltarlas pero al soltarlas en el otro div, no suelta nada 
gracias

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

   function img(){
   var cadena = "";
   var n1 = prompt("Dame el numero de carros ");
 for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
   cadena += "<img src='imagenes/puzzle/sedan4.png'/>";
}
contenedorAuto.innerHTML = cadena;
   }
```

```css
#contenedorAuto{
  background-color: red;
  width: 75px;
  height: 150px;
}
#Estacionamiento{
  background-color: blue;;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section id="contenedorEstacionamiento" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  <h2>Por Favor Estacione los Carros<button onclick="img();">Introduzca el Numero de Carros</button></h2>
  
  <div id="contenedorAuto" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <img id="" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

  <div id="Estacionamiento" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  
        </section>
```

Comment: Pon tu código con la opción fragmento JavaScript, es el icono con la hoja y los simbolos < > adentro

Comment: gracias ya lo inserte

Comment: puse en un solo snippet tu código y falta que agregues que hace la función img()

Comment: se me olvido copiar ese ya lo inserte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente codigo, funciona deacuerdo a lo que necesitas

```js
function drag(ev) {
      console.log("dragStart");
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
      ev.effectAllowed = "copyMove";
   }
   function dragover(ev) {
      console.log("dragOver");
      ev.preventDefault();
   }
   function drop(ev) {
      console.log("Drop");
      ev.preventDefault();
      var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      // copiar el element si el identificador de destino es correcto
      if (id == "auto" && ev.target.id == "Estacionamiento") {
         var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true);
         //despues que clonamos el carro lo eliminamos..
         document.getElementById(id).remove()

         nodeCopy.id = "autoEstacionado";
         ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
         document.querySelector('#Estacionamiento strong span').innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#Estacionamiento img').length
      }
   }
   function dragend(ev) {
      console.log("dragEnd");
      // Eliminar  datos de arrastre
      ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
   }

   function img(){
      var cadena = "";
      var n1 = prompt("Dame el numero de carros ");
      for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
         var img = document.createElement('img');
         img.id = "auto"
         img.draggable = "true"
         img.src = 'http://cdn5.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintados/201112/d6ce39e59a72ada75de877525310da2e.png';

         document.getElementById("contenedorAuto").appendChild(img);
      }
   }
```

```css
div {
   margin: 0em;
   padding: 2em;
}
#autoEstacionado{
   background: #E91E63;
   width: 75px;
   height: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#contenedorAuto{
   background: #fff;
   width: 75px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
#Estacionamiento,#dest_copy, #dest_move {
   border: 5px solid blue;
   width: 300px;
   height: 50;
}
img{
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
   <section>

      <h2> Por Favor Estacione los Carros</h2>
      <button onclick="img();">Introduzca el Numero de Carros</button>

      <div   id="contenedorAuto" ondragstart="drag(event);" ondragend="dragend(event);">
         <strong>auto</strong>
      </div>

      <div id="Estacionamiento" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="dragover(event);">
         <strong>vehiculos sestacionamiento <span>0</span></strong>

      </div>

   </section>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciona pero no entendi bien de la imagen que dice auto de ese lo muevo al cuadro de vehiculos estacionamiento pero necesito usar la funcion de img que me genera el numero solicitado de autos pero igual no se donde poner los autos estacionados los puse en el div de auto y aparecian pero no se movia el carro se movia con todo el cuadro rojo perdon si no me e explicado bien por que soy nuevo en javascript pero solo necesito que si se puedan mover las imagenes que me genera la funcion de img();

Comment: en el proyecto que tengo pongo las imagenes generadas en un div pero al moverlo al otro div no se mueven gracias por tu ayuda espero me puedas seguir apoyando 
Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia le hice unas modificaciones al codigo. espero que te sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba te lo agradesco